# Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation Valgrind c++

Tags: c++, valgrind

So, I get this error when running the command: `--track-origins=yes` on Valgrind

```
==57680== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==57680==    at 0x100584A6B: __dtoa (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==57680==    by 0x1005AB2DD: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==57680==    by 0x1005D1AD2: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==57680==    by 0x1005AA2B1: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==57680==    by 0x1005A841D: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==57680==    by 0x100002466: main (test.cpp:500)
==57680==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==57680==    at 0x100002025: main (test.cpp:336)
```

line 500 is:

```
  printf("Iteration = %d    t = %.10f   p_iter = %d\n", iter, time[iter+1], p_iter);
```

and line 336 is:

```
    double time[iter_max + 1];
```

I don't know what this means? How this time is creating a memory leak issue?

main code example

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "Functions.h"
#include "fftw3.h"
#include <cstring>

int main(){         
    
    // Setting parameters 
    double frequency = 200.0;    
    double dt = 0.1;        
    double tend = 5000.; 
    double err_max = 1e-7;          

    int P_iter_max = 500;      

    int iter_max = tend / dt;
    int saveNumber = 1;

    //Initialize Parameters 

    double *ksqu; 
    ksqu = (double*) fftw_malloc(nx*nyk*sizeof(double));
    memset(ksqu, 42, nx*nyk* sizeof(double)); //initialize for now

    fftw_complex *Pek;
    Pek = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*nyk* sizeof(fftw_complex)); 
    memset(Pek, 42, nx*nyk* sizeof(fftw_complex)); 

    fftw_complex *Pik;
    Pik = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*nyk* sizeof(fftw_complex)); 
    memset(Pik, 42, nx*nyk* sizeof(fftw_complex)); 

    fftw_complex *nuink;
    nuink = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*nyk* sizeof(fftw_complex)); 
    memset(nuink, 42, nx*nyk* sizeof(fftw_complex)); 

    //similarly initialize everything else

    //Save I.Cs 

    int p_iter = Potk(invnk, dndxk, dndyk, Pk, PSk, kx, ky, ninvksq, err_max, P_iter_max);

    double time[iter_max + 1]; 
    time[0] = 0;

    for (int iter = 0; iter < iter_max; iter++){

        calcPSk(dndxk, dndyk, Pik, Pek, nuink, nuiek, nuenk, nueik, isigPk, Oci, Oce, u, B, ksqu, potSourcek);
 
    }

    printf("Iteration = %d    t = %.10f   p_iter = %d\n", iter, time[iter+1], p_iter);
}
```

Comment: `double time[iter_max + 1];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime value.  Instead use `std::vector<double> time(iter_max + 1);`

Comment: or if you want a array instead of a vector use int time[] = new int[iter_max + 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a leak. You are reading uninitialized memory. As @PaulMcKenzie says in the comments, `time` is not standard C++, rather it is a [GCC extension that comes from C99](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

You could use `memset` to ensure that `time` is initialized. Alternatively, you could use `std::vector`, for instance

```
std::vector<double> time(iter_max + 1, 0.0);
```

This will create a vector of size `iter_max + 1` all initialized to 0.0.

However, as it stands, your code is not using the `time` variable other than in the `printf`, so you could simply remove it.

Comment: This makes more sense, however, I have an issue running it even when I `#include<vector>` to my main code I get the following: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >::__vallocate(unsigned long) in testBed-9caf34.o
  "std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::length_error::length_error(char const*) in testBed-9caf34.o` I am not sure why. I am using VS code on mac

Comment: VS code is just a fancy text editor. You compiler is most likely clang, and the error message that you are getting is from the link editor. Most likely whatever VS code does to generate some sort of build project is doing something wrong concerning C++ options and/or libraries.

Comment: Thanks! I was using gcc instead of g++